# Difference Native and Non-Native iOS apps

Tags: ios, native, hybrid-mobile-app

I am not really sure if this is the right place to ask, if it isn't, I am sorry.

I am researching different apps in the same category, and I am trying to figure out how many of them are Native or Non-Native(Hybrid?) apps. Is there any way I can figure this out without seeing the code? What are indicators that an app is Native or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In fact, answer depends on framework which was used for building app. The are two kinds of frameworks that I've seen so far:

1. Based on C/C++ languages (Marmalade SDK, e.g.)
2. Based on JavaScript (Appcelerator Titanium, PhoneGap, etc.)

In first case the only way to recognize that app is not native is to disassemle it and see the compiler-specific features. But it is necessary to know a lot about compilers.

In seconds case, you can recognize it more simple. In such kind of apps you can extract some specific files, like HTML, JavaScript, etc. In case of Appcelerator Titanium you also will have a small JavaScript engine there.

So finally I can say that it is not so easy to recognize the framework which was used for development and building. But if you have some technical skills, you can do it.